# How to prove this inequality with the simplest means?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, inequality

$$ x^2+5y^2+6z^2 \geq 4\sqrt{5xyz^2},\ \text{ if }\ xy>0 $$

I was trying to prove it. The right hand side should be nonnegative, so I can square it on both sides.
But once I have done it I get to a point, where I do not see how to show, that the statement is greater or equal to $0.$

$$x^4+25y^4+36z^4+10x^2y^2+12x^2z^2+60y^2z^2-80xyz^2 \geq 0. $$
Thank you

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: This feels like AM-GM, or possibly C-S...

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: AM-GM inequality: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means#The_inequality  Cauchy-Schwarz inequality: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality#Sedrakyan's_lemma_-_Positive_real_numbers

Comment: In pieces $x^2 + 5y^2 \ge 2\sqrt{5x^2y^2} = 2|x||y|\sqrt 5=2xy\sqrt 5$.  So $(x^2 + 5y^2) + 6z^2 \ge 2xy\sqrt 5 + 6z^2 \ge 2\sqrt{2xy\sqrt 5\cdot 6z^2}=4\sqrt{3\sqrt{5}xyz^2} > 4\sqrt{5xy^2z^2}$.

Comment: Wow. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like the AM.GM inequality will by useful.  We might as well assume $x,y>0$. (As $xy>0$ then either $x,y > 0$ or $x,y < 0$.  If $x,y < 0$ then we can replace $x,y$ with $|x|, |y|$ and the result will be the same.... Or... I'll just use $|x|,|y|$).

By AM.GM we have $x^2 + 5y^2 \ge 2\sqrt{x^2\cdot 5y}=2|x||y|\sqrt 5= 2xy\sqrt 5$.

So $x^2 + 5y^2 + 6z^2 \ge 2xy\sqrt 5 + 6z^2$.

Apply AM.GM on $2xy\sqrt 5$ and $6z^2$ and we have $2xy\sqrt 5 +6z^2 \ge 2\sqrt{2xy\sqrt 5\cdot 6z^2}=2\sqrt{12xyz^2\sqrt 5}=4\sqrt{3\sqrt 5xyz^2}$.

And as $3 > \sqrt 5$ we have $4\sqrt{3\sqrt 5xyz^2}>4\sqrt{\sqrt 5^2xyz^2}=4\sqrt{5xyz^2}$

And that does it.

Comment: great. Thank you!

Comment: How do you type this so quickly? Beat me to it by about 10 minutes...

Comment: This is the first time I've ever been accused typing fast.  I must have started before you did.